# In reduxjs/toolkit on first dispatch() action.payload is undefined, second dispatch() passes correct data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I cannot figure out why on first dispatch() call data passed as prop which it then read by reducer is undefined, but when I instantly call dispatch() again it then passes proper value.

this is how store.ts is defined

```
import addEditLuxmedBenefitSystemsSlice from 'pages/edit-blind/redux/add-edit-benefits-slice';
import { PreloadedState } from 'redux';

export const reducer = combineReducers({
  addEditLuxmedBenefitSystemsSlice: addEditLuxmedBenefitSystemsSlice,
});
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducer>;

export function setupStore(preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) {
  return configureStore({
    reducer,
    preloadedState,
  });
}
```

this is my slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { LuxmedBenefitUserType, BenefitSystemsUserType } from '../types';

export const addEditLuxmedBenefitSystemsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'addEditLuxmedSlice',
  initialState: [] as LuxmedBenefitUserType[],
  reducers: {
    addEditBenefits: (state, action) => {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      console.log(id);
      if (!state.length) {
        state.push(action.payload);
      }
    },
  },
});

export default addEditLuxmedBenefitSystemsSlice.reducer;

export const addEditLuxmedBenefitSystemsActions = addEditLuxmedBenefitSystemsSlice.actions;
```

And here how dispatch() is called in onSubmit funtion:

```
export const LuxmedBenefitComponent = () => {
  const { currentEditBlind } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.editBlind);
  const { id, name, lastName, profileName } = currentEditBlind!;
  const userProps = { id, name, lastName, profileName };
  const [luxmedBenefitUser, setLuxmedBenefitUser] = useState<UserLuxmedBenefitType>();
  const [isFormSubmitted, setIsFormSubmitted] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const displayParagraphHandler = () => {
    setIsFormSubmitted(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsFormSubmitted(false);
    }, 4000);
  };

  const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit, resetForm } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      contractForm: '',
      userRelation: '',
      offerType: '',
      totalPrice: '',
      employerCost: '',
      employeeCost: '',
      comments: '',
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      setLuxmedBenefitUser({ ...userProps, ...values });
      resetForm();
      displayParagraphHandler();
      dispatch(addEditLuxmedBenefitSystemsActions.addEditBenefits(luxmedBenefitUser));
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` hooks are asynchronous.

Inside of `onSubmit`, you call `setLuxmedBenefitUser` and then try to use the newly updated `luxmedBenefitUser`. But, being asynchronous, it hasn't been updated yet.

Simply store the new value as it's own variable so that you can use it in both contexts:

```
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      const updatedLuxmedBenefitUser = {...userProps, ...values};
      setLuxmedBenefitUser(updatedLuxmedBenefitUser);
      resetForm();
      displayParagraphHandler();
      dispatch(addEditLuxmedBenefitSystemsActions.addEditBenefits(updatedLuxmedBenefitUser));
    },
```